# C++ Increase a int smoothly

Tags: c++

I have a int containing a value like this:

```
int CharY = 20;
```

And I want that value to increase with 1 until it is equal to lets say 50.

But I dont want it to do like this:
[image]

I would more likely make the value smoothly increase something like this:

[image]

How can I achive this like in picture number 2 without a ton of code and such?

Comment: Why do you need this? Does the change have to run in a separate thread?

Comment: I'm drawing with DirectX and I need a small cube to increase in the Y axis if I hold down the spacebar button!

Comment: Isn't that a bezier curve? Or, you could chart a graph of `x = radical y` for all positive `y` then  mirror that horizontally and vertically to fill the negative `x`'s. To modify the slopes you just change the equation slightly.

Comment: You can increment it until the target value is reached.

Comment: @Raven Wouldn't it work just with simple increments? Does it have to be curve? Can't it be a line?

Comment: looks like you need to increase delay btw iterations

Comment: @LogicStuff It can be a line just aslong as it increases smoothly like 1 each second but I have no idea on how to achive that.

Comment: How about using a [smoothstep function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothstep)? It is for floats, so you would have to cast the result if you really need integers.

Comment: Looks like a cosine or sign function.  Vary the argument per unit time.  The finer the values of the argument, the better the slopes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are familiar with a little math, you should be able to understand the [window function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function). So let's say 20 is the start point and 50 is the top(middle of window). Pick a function, decide the sample count, use a timer tick and sample a value from the function for every tick.

By the way, I find the welch window easiest.

Gokhan.